# Android Layout messed up when langague is changed

Tags: android, layout

All the strings of my app are in the values/strings.xml and for the spanish language, I have the translated strings in the values-es/strings.xml file. The problem is that, when I change the cellphone from english to spanish, all the layouts change (sizes, gravity) and also the style of the dialogs, in the EditText, etc. Any idea why this happens and how to maintain the same layout of the english version for the spanish?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?  I'm not sure I understand what is happening...

Comment: Also post the file structure, so that we know what are the things that can change on language change.

Comment: It suddenly changed back to normal. Don't know whay yet.